# How to install the apps from sample gallery in a developer edition org?

Tags: lightning-apps, cli

While writing the command on salesforce CLI
**sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n ebikes**
I'am getting an error->
**Permission set "ebikes" not found in target org. Do you need to push source?**
Any solutions for this?

Comment: Did you deploy the application? That command won't work until you do.

Comment: yes, I had deployed it before writing the above-mentioned command.

Answer (score 0):

For a developer edition org, first use:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app
```

Comment: I had written the deploy command before the permset command and then got the above-mentioned error. I'm referring this for installation [link](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-a-developer-edition-org-or-a-trailhead-playground)

Comment: First I had forked that file to my local repo. Then made the changes in the communities metadata file and after that run those commands. I'm not much familiar with the Git, any other step needed?